# Creating work breakdown structure

Tags: diagrams

I have a diagram that I want to convert into latex format. The diagram is as follows:
[image: The Diagram to be done in WBS format]
can someone please tell me how to draw it in Work Breakdown Structure format??

Comment: What is WBS format?

Comment: It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will! It wuld be good it you could at least provide the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

As you didn't provide the text I have mostly repeated the one box.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\infobox[3]{
  \node[anchor=base west,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2mm,
        minimum height=47mm,
        draw=DodgerBlue,thick,fill=DarkTurquoise,text=white] (#2) at #1 {
          \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}\raggedright\quad\\ #3 \end{minipage}
        };
  \node[rectangle,fill=DodgerBlue,text=white,rounded corners] at (#2.north){#2};
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/84mm]
    \draw[black!70,very thick](0,0.1)--node[above]{\Huge The Culprits}(9,0.1) ;
    \infobox{(0,-2)}{Virus}{Hepatitis, SARS, Herpes, Mono, AIDS, HIV, Warts,
    Influenza, Chicken pox, Cold sores, Small pox, Cold germs, Bird flu,
    HSN1, Measles, Norovirus, Tetanus, Yellow fever, Typhoid, Ebola,
    Haemorrhagic fever};
    \infobox{(3.1,-2)}{Bacteria}{Tuberculosis, Pneumonia, Anthrax,
    Urinary tract infection, Staph, Peritonitis, E. coli, Strep
    throat, Typhoid, Stomach ulcers, Salmonella, Tulameria,
    Morgellons, Lyme disease}
    \infobox{(6.2,-2)}{Virus}{Hepatitis, SARS, Herpes, Mono, AIDS, HIV, Warts,
    Influenza, Chicken pox, Cold sores, Small pox, Cold germs, Bird flu,
    HSN1, Measles, Norovirus, Tetanus, Yellow fever, Typhoid, Ebola,
    Haemorrhagic fever};
    \infobox{(1.5,-5.8)}{Virus}{Hepatitis, SARS, Herpes, Mono, AIDS, HIV, Warts,
    Influenza, Chicken pox, Cold sores, Small pox, Cold germs, Bird flu,
    HSN1, Measles, Norovirus, Tetanus, Yellow fever, Typhoid, Ebola,
    Haemorrhagic fever};
    \infobox{(4.6,-5.8)}{Virus}{Hepatitis, SARS, Herpes, Mono, AIDS, HIV, Warts,
    Influenza, Chicken pox, Cold sores, Small pox, Cold germs, Bird flu,
    HSN1, Measles, Norovirus, Tetanus, Yellow fever, Typhoid, Ebola,
    Haemorrhagic fever};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Most of the work is one by the macro `\infobox`, which takes three arguments:

```
\infobox{position}{heading}{text}
```

where the "position" is an `(x,y)`-coordinate. All this macro does is draw two nodes. The first one is a rectangular node that contains the text in a `minipage` environment and the second node is the "heading", which is placed as a rectangular node at the top of the previous box.